# Calculated member in SSAS cube based on two dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube, mdx-query

I would like to create a calculated member within my Calculations inside a SSAS cube, but it has to be based on two separate dimensions (I don't know how to call it in a different, maybe "better" way..). Below there is a picture what I mean:

[image: New calculated member]

I need member "FYE" based on values from two dimensions - "Time Calculations" and "Analysis". From "Time Calculations" I have to sum up "YTD" (but only "Actual" from dimension "Analysis") with "ROY" (but only "Budget" from dimension "Analysis"). Is it even possible? If so then how? Thank you for any help in that case :)

Comment: Don't you sum metrics? the YTD = 100 there is metric not dimension right?

Comment: Can you give us the query you use?

Comment: it would help a lot if we know a bit about how you cube looks and what exactly you want to do.

Comment: YTD is a member of dimension "Time Calculations", I don't have a query because it will be calculated member within calculations in the cube. Unfortunately, I don't have a idea how to prepare correct MDX. 
I thought that something like this (code below) will give me what I need but it looks that it doesn't work as I want...

([DimTimeCalculations].[Time Calculations].[YTD], [DimAnalysis].[Analysis].&[Actual]) + ([DimTimeCalculations].[Time Calculations].[ROY], [DimAnalysis].[Analysis].&[Budget])

Comment: Scope doesn't matter for me, I would like to have FYE based on what I wrote for each level on hierarchy when I query cube and use "Time Calculations" and "FYE" member within it - that's pretty simple. I know that it should be sum of YTD (but only Actual) and ROY (but only Budget). That's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define measures that return 100 and 600 from your example. Once you have done that, create a calc measure equal to `([DimTimeCalculations].[Time Calculations].[YTD], [DimAnalysis].[Analysis].&[Actual], [Measures].[<measure to produce 100>]) + ([DimTimeCalculations].[Time Calculations].[ROY], [DimAnalysis].[Analysis].&[Budget],[Measures].[,<measure to produce 600>])`.

One caveat - this CM will produce identical results for all members of `[DimTimeCalculations].[Time Calculations]` and `[DimAnalysis].[Analysis]` hierarchies. To fix that you need to create scope assignments for individual members.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, at least now I understand and can maybe tweak this a little bit more :) Thank you!